# Динамическое изменение location адреса в wsdl

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

Есть WCF-сервис, написанный на C#, экспортирующий пользовательскую WSDL-схему с помощью атрибута

```
externalMetadataLocation
```

Предполагается, что сервис будет развернут на нескольких серверах с разными доменными именами, и соответственно, встал вопрос о том, как динамически изменять значение атрибута location параметра soap::address в WSDL. Возможно ли это и, если да, то как?

Я пробовал переопределять поведение при экспорте WSDL с помощью `SoapExtensionReflector`
но это не работает.